# Custom RSS feed with custom url

Tags: rss, feed

I'm trying to create custom RSS feed that will contain one post type and posts there from just one category. URL to this feed should be `/rss`.

I tried some plugins but didn't found any that will help me with this. Also, I used some plugin to disable feeds from core because I don't need them anymore.

Is there some way to achieve this and how? Some plugins or examples would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to [customize feeds](https://codex.wordpress.org/Customizing_Feeds). In your case, what you want to do is disable to normal rss feed and replace it with a template of your own. Like this:

```
remove_action ('do_feed_rss','do_feed_rss',10,1);
```

This line is a bit confusing. The first `do_feed_rss` is the name of the action hook. The second is the [default function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_feed_rss/) on that hook. Now you can add a new action:

```
add_action( 'do_feed_rss', 'wpse305438_custom_rss', 10, 1 );
function wpse305438_custom_rss () {
   load_template( TEMPLATEPATH . '/my-custom-feed.php');
   }
```

Beware that by default WordPress will relay `/rss` to `/feed`. Changing that involves hooking into [`rewrite_rules_array`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/rewrite_rules_array).

Comment: Additional external link: http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/201103/controlling_and_customising_rss_feeds_in_wordpress/